# Lightning Experience lead conversion shows empty picklist for Converted Status

Tags: lightning, lead-conversion

I created a path for the lead conversion process. Now I reached the final step in my path in Lightning Experience, and I am trying to convert my lead.

However, the Converted Status picklist is empty:
[image]

If I do the same process in Classic, I can pick from the following available values for the lead Converted Status:

[image]

My question is: Is this a bug? Does anyone have any suggestions on solving this?

As additional information I can say that

- There are no lead record types besides -Master-,
- I just created a new developer edition, as I thought the old one might be filled up with too many Trailhead challenges, but maybe this does not sem to be the case.
- I have deactivated all existing (4) lead statusses and used my own, and my
  own lead statusses include a total of 8 statusses, where 1 is
  the default, and 1 is converted.
- I have set Preserve Lead Status = false under Lead Settings
- There is only 1 lead process, and all lead status values are added for the process.
- There is only 1 path created, and this is for leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, please check: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gWcQAI

So, make sure that API name and label name of picklist values match, then it should work.

Good luck!